# Way to fetch calendar data from Microsoft teams?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have to fetch calendar data from Microsoft teams, When i searched about it, i got to know it can be only done by Microsoft's graph API.

Since Microsoft's Graph is an SDK it needs authentication, for that i have to enable permission to use various API's, otherwise getting this error.

```
GraphError {
  statusCode: 403,
  code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
  message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
  requestId: 'b82d6a78-ca52-48bf-95dc-da4393e95286',
  date: 2021-03-22T06:36:20.000Z,
  body: '{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2021-03-22T12:06:20","request-id":"b82d6a78-ca52-48bf-95dc-da4393e95286","client-request-id":"59fcd2e0-db2f-8dab-a1bf-58ff6dddda1f"}}'
}
```

For permissions, I can't find the grant permission thingy here -

[image]

How to authenticate in this case, it asks to be a Microsoft partner first !!

Comment: Are you building an internal app for your company? If so, that's not a problem, you only need to have a partner registered if you are building multi-tenant apps

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow what's a partner, you mean my company needs to be registered as ms partners ?

Comment: You can see more here: https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/support/?stage=1 . To my knowledge, yes, I think your company would need to be registered, but there's no cost. As I said, this is only if you are developing solutions for other companies - if this is an internal app, it's not required

Comment: I agree with @HiltonGiesenow above. You need to have proper permission in your token. Validate the token in [https://jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and see if you have any permissions. Please make sure to add [any related permissions specified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: Hi @Vedsinha, Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Yeah, it got resolved, had to go through the Microsoft developers program and create an account there and register on the azure-ad portal @Sridevi-MSFT